# close httpserver connection clicking on button in java

Tags: java, javafx, network-programming

I wrote a httpServer in javafx, created a button in UI called **startserver** , server starts on click of that button , how can I close the socket connection by clicking on the same button

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        httpServer.createContext("/", new myhttpHandler());
        httpServer.setExecutor(null);
        httpServer.start();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

static class myhttpHandler implements HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {

        String requestMethod = he.getRequestMethod();
        if (requestMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {

            int responseCode_OK = 200;
            String response = " my http server working ";
            he.sendResponseHeaders(responseCode_OK, response.length());
            OutputStream outputStream = he.getResponseBody();
            outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        }
        he.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start and stop using the same button, perhaps a ToggleButton would serve you better. You can check the toggle state whether to start or stop the HttpServer.

Otherwise you would need to check if the server is running.

```
boolean isRunning ...
if (isRunning) {
    httpServer.stop();
} else {
    httpServer.start();
}
```